# Vue.js - how to reactively add "multi-level-nested" member to object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using vue.js version 2 in a web project.

I know that reactivity has some constraints about adding new members to objects.

That said, I am working with a relatively complex data object that has a multitude of nested members, arrays of sub-objects and so on.

I am now using computed properties to get/set some of these members in specific components, and I am getting/setting those nested properties using lodadh `_.set`

For example: `_.set(myObj, 'GeneralData.Body[0].MainAddress.StreetNumber')`

My issue is that, apart from `GeneralData`, the remaining part could not exist and thus the whole thing is not reactive.

How can I achieve this in vue.js?
I tried to use the `$set` function provided by vue.js but it creates a single nested property named 'GeneralData.Body[0].MainAddress.StreetNumber' (as a string) and not the *object tree* as the lodash function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `_.setWith` which lets you tell `lodash` what function to use to create props.

So, solution to your problem will be like:

```
_.setWith(myObj, 'GeneralData.Body[0].MainAddress.StreetNumber', 'somevalue', function(nsValue, key, nsObject){
 return Vue.set(nsObject, key, nsValue)
})
```

**Reference:**

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#setWith

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set

Comment: Smart. Wasn't aware of _.setWith. It's basically the same answer as mine with a callback function. +1

Comment: Just spent last two hours investigating this, but seems like in this approach the leaf property eg. `.StreetNumber`  will not become reactive. (I noticed that in chrome-dev-tools despite holding/parent object `.MainAddress`  being an observable (it has `__ob__ : Observable` property) the actual `.StreetNumber` doesn't not seem to be reactive as it DOES 
NOT have `reactiveGetter StreetNumber` and `reactiveSetter StreetNumber`). If we use @Ohgodwhy s solution, the `.StreetNumber` will have reactiveSetter and reactiveGetter...

Answer (score 4):

Assign your object to a variable first:

```
const objToDeploy = myObj

_.set(objToDeploy, 'GeneralData.Body[0].MainAddress.StreetNumber')
```

Then when you're done, assign that with `Vue.set`

```
Vue.set(this, 'myObj', objToDeploy)
```

You should know that work with these heavy nested data sets and reactive properties will cause an entire re-draw of the Virtual DOM because of how the `Observable` reactivity works in Vue. Therefore it is best to split your `array of multi nested sub objects` into their own `Models` where you don't have this issue.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the issue about virtual DOM and reactivity. Unfortunately at the moment I cannot re-engineer the UI to avoid this, but I will definetly keep this as a task for the future

Comment: This seems to be more reliable solution than @pranavjindal999